# Every $k$ vertices in an $k$ - connected graph are contained in a cycle.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph. Meaning, $G$ has no fewer than $k$ vertices, and for every set of $k-1$ or fewer vertices, if we remove them from $G$, the graph stays connected (Of course, $G$ itself is also connected).

I want to prove that for any $k>1$, if $G$ is $k$-connected, then every set of $k$ vertices is contained in a cycle.

I have tried some ways - mainly using induction by removing one of the vertices of the set from the graph, and/or using Menger's theorem to construct the cycle. But I always encounter problems with making sure that the cycle I'm building deosn't have repeating edges etc.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Won't you have to allow the cycle to have repeated edges?  Otherwise how could a vertex of degree one be in a cycle?

Comment: @TaraB: A $2$-connected graph has no vertices of degree $1$.

Comment: @Chris:  Yes, thanks, I had just realised that and was about to delete my comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a rough argument:

Take a cycle $C$ containing as many of the $k$ designated vertices as possible. If cycle has all the k designated vertices then you are done. Otherwise, By Menger's theorem , you can choose k paths from a missing vertex to the cycle $C$. The end points of the paths in $C$ divide $C$ into $k$ segments. One of the segments does not contain any of the designated vertices. Replace that segment by the two paths connecting the ends of the segment to the missing vertex.

Comment: What if there are two vertices v1,v2 not in C and we replace missing segment of C with path contaning v1 and in the next step for v2, the segment containing v1 is demanded to be replaced?

Comment: Remember that the segment you replace does not contain any of the designated vertices. That is the key point of the proof.

Comment: yes .. I got it .. for some reason I have misread the proof :)

Comment: Should'nt you mention that we need C to have at least k vertices? How can it be shown?

Comment: @35T41 No. If C has less than k vertices, then trivially there will be at least one of the designated vertices, say $x_k$ not in the cycle. Then we can find vertex disjoint paths from it to every one of the vertices in the existing cycle C, and we are free to slot $x_k$ in between any two of these adjacent vertices. In that way, we can always construct a cycle of size at least $k+1$.

Comment: Hey, what about if the two paths to the segment which does not contain any of the designated vertices necessarily contain other parts of  your cycle, and you therefore end up having to exclude some portion of the cycle having some of the designated vertices, every time you try to include remainig ones!

Answer (score 4):

It should be an induction statement, the induction is on $k$.

Base of induction begins with $k=2$. We know every $u,v \in V$ have at least two vertex-disjoint paths (this is by Menger's theorem) $P_1=(v,...,u)$ and $P_2=(v,...,u)$ , we notice $P_1P_2$  is a cycle. $u$ and $v$ are both in it which means for every set $S$ of vertices with $ |S|=2$ we have such a cycle.

Induction hypothesis is that for $(k-1)$-connectedness the statement holds. That is, take any set $S$ of vertices with $|S|=k-1$ in $(k-1)$-connected graph and you'll have them sitting on a cycle $C$.

So now it's left to take arbitrary $v \in V$ in a $k$-connected graph, remove it, and this gives us a $(k-1)$-connected graph and so any set $|S|=k-1$ sits on a circle and now it's only left to look at $v$ - as suggested above using Menger's theorem and creating a cycle.