# 3-Points on 3-vertex connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I have to proof the following

> Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be any 3 vertices on a 3-vertex-connected graph $G=(V,E)$. Then they belong to a circle $C$

What I got so far.

Any two vertices $ v_1,v_2 \in V$ are on a circle $C$. There exist 3 disjoint vertices $u_1, u_2,u_3$ in $C$ such that paths from $u$ to $u_i$ with $u \notin C$ are pairwise disjoint and $u_i$ is the only vertex in that path belonging to $C$ .

How can I continue from here ?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I edited my problem. I meant the connectivity of the graph and not the number of vertices. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I don't know if by "circle" you mean something more restricted than a *cycle*.  While there is a notion of a *circle graph*, based on intersections among chords of a circle, that seems unrelated to your problem.

Comment: In general, every subset of $k$ vertices in a $k$-connected graph are contained in a cycle: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156032/every-k-vertices-in-an-k-connected-graph-are-contained-in-a-cycle